# String concatenation NASM

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am trying to concatenate two strings into another string for an attempt at a FizzBuzz implementation in assembly. My database values look something like this:

```
buffer:  times 10 db 0
fizz:   db "Fizz"       ; Length of each is 4, so add 4.
buzz:   db "Buzz"
```

What I've been trying to do is something like`mov buffer, [fizz]`. However, whenever I try something like this, NASM says `invalid combination of opcode and operands`. I am learning assembly on my own and am just starting, so I'm sorry if this might seem obvious.

Comment: You cant just copy data from one memory location to another like this. Have a look at the string instructions. `movsb` is probably a good place to start, followed by `movsw` and `movsd`. But basically, point the source at fizz, point the dest at buffer and copy 4 bytes. Reposition the source to point to buzz and then copy another 4 bytes.

Comment: In this case, with the two strings both having 4 characters, and the target buffer being initialized to all zeroes, you could also do something like: `mov eax, [fizz]` /  `mov [buffer], eax` / `mov eax, [buzz]` / `mov [buffer+4], eax`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NASM the identifier *buffer* only represents the **address** of your variable *buffer* and the symbol *buffer* is treated as an immediate value.
When you wrote `mov buffer, [fizz]` you actually asked to move a memory content to an immediate which is just impossible!

One way to do this copy then is by using an intermediate register.

```
mov eax, [fizz]
mov [buffer], eax
mov eax, [buzz]
mov [buffer+4], eax
```

If you couldn't spare the register then use

```
push dword [fizz]
pop  dword [buffer]
push dword [buzz]
pop  dword [buffer+4]
```

Comment: I might be misunderstanding this, but when you surround a name with brackets (e.g. [buffer]), then you are saying the _value_ inside buffer.  If the content of buffer is larger than a doubleword, how do you push or pop it?

Comment: @WilliamWisdom In your program _buffer_ has 10 bytes. To `push` its entire contents (respecting the endianness of X86) you would write: `push word [buffer+8]` push dword [buffer+4]` push dword [buffer]`